jq parse string array and string object
I have this json string:
json_string="{\"emailRecipients\":\"['test@example.com', 'tes2t@example.com', 'test3@example.com']\", \"anotherEmails\":\"{'test1': 'test1@example.com', 'test2': 'test2@example.com', 'test3': 'test3@example.com'}\", \"some_key\": 3, \"another_key\": \"some_value\"}"

I'm trying to use jq to parse the emailRecipients as a json array and anotherEmails as a json object.
I'm trying to make a command that can work with any key, not emailRecipients just and anotherEmails. I also need to keep keys-values that don't have json objects/arrays inside intact.
So I tried to do this:
parsed_json=$(echo "$json_string" | jq 'with_entries(
    .value |= if startswith("\"[") and endswith("\"]") then
        gsub("''";"\"") | fromjson
    else
        .
    end
)')

But I don't know why the gsub isn't working. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

why is there gsub at all? "''" that's double '', not single '.

Why do you want to parse non-JSON as JSON?

You want to break out of the shell's string (delimited by '), and add the single quote from there (e.g. delimited by "): jq '(.[] | strings | select(test("^\\[.*\\]$"))) |= (gsub("'"'"'";"\"") | fromjson)' <<< "$json_string"

However, just replacing single quotes with double quotes does not guarantee to get you valid JSON. The JSON encoding actually extends beyond a mere string delimiter character. Better try to have the provider of your input produce valid JSON in the first place.

I really svck at dealing with json with bash. In fact these values are actually json values they're just encapsulated in double quotes by Airflow at runtime and I have no control over that. @pmf your solution and knittl's both worked.
Thanks alot !

"In fact these values are actually json values", no they are not valid JSON. JSON strings and object keys have to be enclosed in double quotes only; single quotes are not permitted.

You seem to be confusing syntax with values. The quotes are not part of the value; the value starts and ends with [ and ], respectively (not "[ and "]; the latter doesn't even make sense if the syntax quote was part of the value). To detect objects, you need to check for { and } prefix and suffix. You need to filter for string values, otherwise you cannot apply the startswith filter.
Note that your values are not valid JSON. However, if you still want to continue, here's the full program:
map_values(
    if type == "string" and (startswith("[") and endswith("]") or startswith("{") and endswith("}")) then
        gsub("'"; "\"") | fromjson
    else
        .
    end
)

When used in a shell context:
parsed_json=$(printf '%s\n' "$json_string" | jq 'map_values(
    if type == "string" and (startswith("[") and endswith("]") or startswith("{") and endswith("}")) then
        gsub("'\''"; "\"") | fromjson
    else
        .
    end
)')

or
parsed_json=$(printf '%s\n' "$json_string" | jq "map_values(
    if type == \"string\" and (startswith(\"[\") and endswith(\"]\") or startswith(\"{\") and endswith(\"}\")) then
        gsub(\"'\"; \"\\\"\") | fromjson
    else
        .
    end
)")

